# Create a pandas dataframe column based on a logical test

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing the following columns:

```
amount1 - a numeric value
amount2 - a different numeric value
ccy1 - a 3-char currency code
ccy2 - a different 3-char currency code
```

The data is organised such that there are rows where the tuple (amount1,ccy1,amount2,ccy2) will correspond exactly with another row consisting of the tuple (amount2,ccy2,amount1,ccy1)

What I want to do is split my dataframe into two. In df1 I want to include those rows where ccy1 >= ccy2 (sorted alphabetically) and in df2, I want to include those rows where cc1 < ccy2.

I wrote a simple function that does the splitting:

```
def splitfunctest(s1, s2):
   if s1 > s2:
      return 'BIG'
   else:
      return 'SMALL'
```

But am having trouble applying it to my new column I am trying :

```
df['splitter'] = splitfunctest(df['ccy1'], df['ccy2'])
```

but get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 1, in 
>    File "", line 2, in splitfunctest
>   ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

So I can see that the function is trying (and failing) to evaluate the entire contents of each field passed to it - So how do I get it to function atomically? - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1 = df[df['ccy1'] >= df['ccy2']]
df2 = df[df['ccy1'] < df['ccy2']]
```

Comment: That works nicely thankyou!

On the wider question of writing the result of a function into a column, is there a standard practice, or common and performant method of doing that?

Comment: I was also just able to find use of the "loc" command - again, not quite what I want to do but:

`code
     df.[SPLITTER']="None" </br>

     df.loc[(df['ccy1'] >= df['ccy2']), 'SPLITTER'] = 'BIG'

     df.loc[(df['ccy1'] < df['ccy2']), 'SPLITTER'] = 'SMALL'

`
Ideally, I'd like a one-liner that allows me to abstract the workings off into a separately defined function that takes columns/column-names as parameters.

Comment: I think, you might want to use `df.apply` as: `df['SPLITTER'] = df.apply(lambda series: 'BIG' if series['ccy1'] >= series['ccy2'] else 'SMALL', axis=1)`

Comment: That's even better - thankyou so much, this works perfectly now - Final query from me - is it possible to encapsulate the lambda definition `lambda series: 'BIG' if series['ccy1'] >= series['ccy2'] else 'SMALL'` into a `def` somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can always use `def` instead of `lambda`.